# Value cannot be NULL when saving DataGridView to SQL dB

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I have a form with a datagridview (ViewCustomersForm) and a save button.

What I am trying to do is get the user to edit the infotmation in the datagrid view and then hit a save button, which will save the values back to my SQL table.

Unfortunately though, when my save button is pressed I get the following error.

"Value cannot be null."

Pointing at this line of code:

```
dataadapter.Update(ds.Tables("Customers_table"))
```

In the context of the below code:

```
Private Sub ViewCustomersForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Customers._Customers' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Dim connStr As String = "server=barry-laptop\SQLEXPRESS; database=BillingReferenceData; integrated security=yes"
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Customers"
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connStr)
    Dim comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    Dim dataadapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(comm)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()

    '---open the connection and fill the dataset---
    conn.Open()
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Customers_table")
    conn.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "Customers_table"


End Sub

Private Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim connStr As String = "server=barry-laptop\SQLEXPRESS; database=BillingReferenceData; integrated security=yes"
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Customers"
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connStr)
    Dim comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim dataadapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(comm)

    Dim sqlCmdBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(dataadapter)
    sqlCmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
    dataadapter.Update(ds.Tables("Customers_table"))

End Sub
```

I am relatively new to VB, so any help or pointers greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There's a column in your database that requires a value.  You are not providing a value for it, hence the error.

Comment: The only required field in my table is customer_id and I am just trying to update an existing dB record - So that value is already set.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to have by variables defined at the Class level, not with in the Subs.

Here is the working code.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.Common

Public Class ViewCustomersForm
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
Dim connStr As String = "server=barry-laptop\SQLEXPRESS; database=BillingReferenceData; integrated security=yes"
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Customers"
Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connStr)
Dim comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(Sql, conn)
Dim dataadapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(comm)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub ViewCustomersForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    '---open the connection and fill the dataset---
    conn.Open()
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Customers_table")
    conn.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "Customers_table"


End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim sqlCmdBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(dataadapter)
    sqlCmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
    dataadapter.Update(ds.Tables("Customers_table"))

End Sub

End Class
```